# error when using solr and Integrating nutch and solr(HTTP ERROR 500)

Tags: solr, integration, web-crawler, nutch

I have Linux Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I'm trying to install nutch 1.5.1 and solr 3.6.1 and integrate theme together to crawl seed urls.
I'm using [This](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) tutorial to get this work.
I followed the steps before 3.2 and skipped to [step 4](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search) and I can access to
localhost:8983/solr/admin/

without error.
but when going to step 6 and copying schema.xml from conf folder of nutch to example/solr/conf folder of solr
solr/admin page occurs a java error,below:

[image: first part of page]
[image: second part]

How can I handle that?

one more thing to ask....
I have another [tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/61813114/Running-Nutch-Solr) for this that looks good but in first step it mentions that add some code to nutch-site.xml file in /conf/ and /runtime/local/conf/ folder

but in nutch folder there is no runtime folder.In step 4 this folder mentioned too.
any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is just bit of red herring.  The line that specifies version number something like:

```
<schema name="nutch" version="1.5.1">
```

is causing it because the value of version is being parsed as float.  remove the extra dot.  Change it to 1.5 or 1.51 to make it valid float and restart your solr instance.  The exception should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Check,please, whether are Nutch 1.5.1 and Solr 3.6.1 compatible (are they having same versions of lucene-core and solr-solrj jars). I got some problems with incompatible versions, but not with 1.5/3.6 .